# pandas/numpy encoding takes ever to complete

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to export data from MS-SQL table to xlsx using pandas/numpy. Single table contains data for year 2013 through 2016 and I need to export yearly data in seperate excel workbook. 
After export, each workbook will have approximately 150K records with 50 columns.

Following code works, however it takes ever to completely export all the records. It just keep running (more than 8 hrs). 
I am not sure if encoding causes this delay, but my data contains some weird characters that doesn't allow this code to execute without adding encoding.

Help please?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pan

def executeQuery(self, year1): 
        conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;Trusted_Connection=True;'% (dbserver))
        df = pan.read_sql_query(query + year1, conn)
        return df


def exportXL(self, path):
    year = ['2013', '2014', '2015', '2016']
    for x in year:
        data = self.executeQuery(x)
        data = self.encode(data)

        writer = pan.ExcelWriter(filename)
        data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = x, engine='xlsxwriter', index=False)
        writer.save()
    pass


def encode(self, dataframe):
    for a in dataframe.select_dtypes([np.object]).columns[:]:
        dataframe[a] = dataframe[a].str.decode('ISO-8859-1').str.encode('utf-8')
    return dataframe
```

Comment: Are you sure that the script doesn't work without the encoding step? [The docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) say encoding is only necessary for the xlst engine, you're using xlsxwriter. If that doesn't work, you can try setting the encoding in `to_excel`, e.g. `data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = x, engine='xlsxwriter', index=False, encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: You should post that as the answer so that other people will know what solved your problem.